# How to conceptually interpret output of a polynomial (quadratic) regression, when the regressors are orthogonal/correlated

Tags: regression, polynomials, quadratic, orthogonal

I want to show an inverted U-shape relationship between two variables: "minutes spent in a room A" and "trustworthiness in others". The hypothesis is that those who have low and high trustworthiness are the ones who spend the least amount of time in room A, whereas those with medium level-trustworthiness spend the most time in that room.

For this reason, I calculated an polynomial regression in R using the poly function. I have been reading about the different arguments that the function can have, depending on whether the linear and quadratic regressor should be considered as orthogonal or raw regressors.

The output for the "raw" polynomial regression is as follows:

```
                      Estimate    p value
Intercept             274.62      <2e-16***     
poly(x,2,raw=TRUE)1   2.65        0.0007***
poly(x,2,raw=TRUE)2   -0.038      0.001**

Adj. R-squared: 0.18
F-statistic: 6.49 (2,46); p=0.003
```

The output for the "orthogonal" polynomial regression is as follows:

```
                      Estimate     p value
Intercept             308.9       <2e-16***     
poly(x,2,raw=FALSE)1  39.11        0.21
poly(x,2,raw=FALSE)2  -102.7       0.001**

Adj. R-squared: 0.18
F-statistic: 6.49 (2,46); p=0.003
```

Now, reading through questions (and answers) of others, in my model, the linear and quadratic regressors seem to be highly correlated as the raw and orthogonal output is vastly different considering their own p-values and beta-weights. I would interpret that in the "raw" model, both predictors are significant but not on their own, their significance is dependent on both regressors being in the model (because they are strongly correlated, (actually r = 0.94)). In the "orthogonal" model, the regressors are considered independently. Therefore one could conclude that the orthogonal model is the right choice and the result shows that the relationship can be significantly described by a quadratic fit, rather than a linear fit. Note: calculating the linear fit only results in an insignificant fit with an Rsquared under 1%, whereas in the polynomial fits, it goes up to 18% - which is still not fantastic, but still better:

```
                      Estimate     p value
Intercept             3018         <2e-16***     
x                     3.69         0.327

Adj. R-squared: -0.00041
F-statistic: 6.49 (1,46); p=0.327
```

However, when interpreting the beta-weights, I would still need to use the coefficients from the raw model in order to make sensible predictions. So if one cannot interpret the beta-weights in the orthogonal models because in fact the two regressors are inherently correlated, can the above conclusion about better fit really be made?

ps. the QQ plots for the residuals as well as the normality checks using Shapiro-Wilk indicate that the prerequisites for the regression model are met

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)